# How to load external App.Config dynamically in C# Console application?

Tags: c#

I have a console application and the App.Config is outside the appdomain, I want to load it programmatically(not with powershell). I already pass the path of the external App.Config as a command argument but I don't know how to load it in the appdomain once I run the application.

Comment: try from this link https://developers.de/blogs/bahro/archive/2016/02/08/using-external-config-files-in-net-applications.aspx

Comment: I've checked this article. The difference is that I have no config files in my app, the one that gets generated "filename.exe.config"has only some metadata about nugets and that's all. The one config file that there is - is external, I need to load it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

for load app config you can use below code:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

var readerConnectionString = builder.Build().GetSection("Parameter")
                                 .GetSection("DbConnectionRead").Value;
```

and this is a JSON sample:

```
{
    "Parameter":
 {    
    "DbConnectionRead": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm talking about an App.Config file in .Net 4.7  - I'm not talking about .net core. If you have another answer take some time again to reply please.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you can edit your App.Config from outside folder. Here is something I found about reading appsettings from App.Config outside of project folder.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntializeConfigurationFile();

            var check = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn"];
        }

static void IntializeConfigurationFile()
        {
            //ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

            // Get the current configuration associated
            // with the application.
            System.Configuration.Configuration config =
               ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            // Associate the auxiliary with the default
            // configuration file. 
            System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection appSettings = config.AppSettings;
            appSettings.File = "C:\\Personal\\Learning\\Docs\\App.config";

            // Save the configuration file.
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

            // Force a reload in memory of the 
            // changed section.
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("configuration");
        }
```

I have place my App.Config in C:\ drive. But your App.Config should be like this, only appsetting element to be added in your App.Config.

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="conn" value="test" />
    </appSettings>
```

So Basically what it does is when you call the `IntializeConfigurationFile()` method it writes appsetting location to your local path in your `filename.exe.config`. In the project I have tried was added like this

[image]

Reference: [AppSettingsSection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.appsettingssection?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)